# Visual C++: buggy towupper

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, unicode

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cwctype>
#include <clocale>

int main()
{
    wchar_t c = L'\u00ff'; // ÿ LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS
                // → 0178 Ÿ latin capital letter y with diaeresis

    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase;
#ifdef WIN32
    const char * lcc = setlocale(LC_ALL, "English");
#else
    const char * lcc = std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.cp1252");
#endif
    if(lcc) {
        std::cout << "set locale: " << lcc << std::endl;
        std::cout << "towupper(" << (std::wint_t)c << ") = " << towupper(c) << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "failed to set locale" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If I compile and run it in Visual Studio 2010 (also 2013), the result is:

```
set locale: English_United States.1252
towupper(0xff) = 0x9f
```

On Linux with gcc:

```
set locale: en_US.cp1252
towupper(0xff) = 0x178
```

The result of towupper is different on the two platforms, and linux/gcc gives the answer that seems to be correct to me, as the 0x178 (Ÿ) is the correct uppercase Unicode code point for 0xff (ÿ).

However, 0x9f is also a code point for Ÿ, but in the used Windows-1252 code page. So it looks like as if Visual C's towupper would treat the input as a narrow char, and interpret it according to the preset code page.

As for my understanding, the wide characters should always be interpreted as Unicode code points, UTF-16 on Windows/VC, and UTF-32 on Linux/gcc. Am I wrong here, or is it really a bug in the Microsoft implementation? Or is just the specification not strict enough in this situation, and both could be treated as correct result?

Comment: You are explicitly setting your locale to CP1252, which is an 8 bit encoding. If anything I would say that the abnormal version is the Linux one, because there should be no character available beyond 0xff (and you'd be wasting at least 1 byte for each character in a wstring).

Comment: Documented behavior for the MSVC CRT: "The case conversion of towupper is locale-specific".  For Linux: "This function is not very appropriate for dealing with Unicode characters".

Comment: @user846250 As far as I understand towupper should treat the input as a Unicode code point, thus not interpret it according to any code page. So the code page setting of the locale should be irrelevant. There is the toupper variant (without the 'w') that should interpret the input according to the code page.

Comment: @HansPassant That could be a reason, as it is not elaborated in what terms is towupper locale dependent. But I would think that it's locale dependency is to treat correctly the cases like the Turkish dotted and dotless i: I/ı and İ/i, versus the English I/i uppercase/lowercase pairs. And also, the Unicode code point U+009F is a control character that is not supposed to be the uppercase pair of any other character.

Comment: Your assumption that the C language caters to Unicode is just misplaced.  It would inevitably have upset somebody, ISO committees tend to find it easier to inconvenience everybody.  Use ICU.

Comment: @HansPassant So you suggest we don't use any locale sensitive part of the standard library, - as the standard does not say anything about the input encoding, or Unicode usage, - but use some third party library instead? (ICU, or on Windows the internal functions also seems to work well, like CharLowerW.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments on the question, it seems that there is no "true" solution; the C or C++ standard is simply not strict enough regarding the character encodings, so we cannot have real expectations for locale sensitive results.

For my specific use case on Windows, CharUpperW turned out to be a viable option, although it's platform dependent.